# SQL Select when table contains several identical records for a particular feature

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table:

```
|    id_record    |   code     |      date   |
---------------------------------------------
|      12395      |    90      | 23-11-2016  |
|      18733      |    90      | 05-10-2016  |
|      10084      |    9201    | 13-10-2016  |
|      10400      |    9000    | 23-11-2016  |
```

Input parameter `@date` (datetime). `@date='24-11-2016'`.  I want to receive :

```
|    id_record    |   code     |      date   |
---------------------------------------------
|      12395      |    90      | 23-11-2016  |
|      10084      |    9201    | 13-10-2016  |
|      10400      |    9000    | 23-11-2016  |
```

*i.e.* I want to get each code which `max(date)<=@date` and `distinct code` value. which request I have to use ?

Comment: If that is the case, then record `|      18733      |    90      | 05-10-2016  |` is also less than date `'24-11-2016'`.

Comment: Also are you using both MySQL and SQL-SERVER?

Comment: Sorry, I use only SQL-server.  Yes, It is,the record  `| 18733 | 90 | 05-10-2016 |` is also less than date `'24-11-2016'`, but I need selection by  `'code'` and  `'date'` . And the argument `'code'` must be distinct with `max(date)<='24-11-2016'`

Comment: That is fine. What is the query which you have tried out for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table3
    (id_record int, code int, date varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table3

VALUES
    (12395, 90, '23-11-2016'),
    (18733, 90, '05-10-2016'),
    (10084, 9201, '13-10-2016'),
    (10400, 9000, '23-11-2016')



    with cte as (
        select  *,row_number() over(partition by code order by date desc) as rn from Table3
        )
        select id_record,code,date from cte where rn=1 and date<='24-11-2016'
```

Comment: If use your query, I will get only `'date'` , but I need to get `id_record, code, date`

Comment: i ediited my answer can u check once @Kris